# Flutter Format Exception : Unexpected Character (at character 1)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I am getting a Exception in Flutter project. The error looks like below:

```
Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
^
)
```

This is showing in the "throw error" line. The code is below:

```
Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url =
        "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=AIzaSyC9Rz9CDv-_hc68I_wdvogF2ZnDHCpr2Y8";
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
            "returnSecureToken": true,
          },
        ),
      );
      print(response.body);
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData["error"] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData["error"]["message"]);
      }
      _token = responseData["idToken"];
      _userId = responseData["localId"];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(
            responseData["expiresIn"],
          ),
        ),
      );
      _autoLogout();
      notifyListeners();
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final userData = json.encode(
        {
          "token": _token,
          "userId": _userId,
          "expiryDate": _expiryDate.toIso8601String(),
        },
      );
      prefs.setString("userData", userData);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;           //Exception is showing here
    }
  }
```

[Error message looks like this as shown in the image (Click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTUb3.png)

Debug Console is showing the following message:

```
I/flutter (18432): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (18432): <html lang=en>
I/flutter (18432):   <meta charset=utf-8>
I/flutter (18432):   <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
I/flutter (18432):   <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
I/flutter (18432):   <style>
I/flutter (18432):     *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/brand
I/flutter (18432): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (18432): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (18432): ^
```

Please help

Comment: Your HTTP request resulted in a 404 Not Found error, so your HTTP response contains the contents of an error page that would normally be shown.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanx for replying, but please tell me how do i fix it.

Comment: Well, you need to fix your HTTP request so that it goes to the right location.  Currently it generates a 404 error.  You'll need to debug this yourself.  Verify that the URL of the request is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My endpoints were wrong in the http url. I was using some older endpoints in my http url.

According to the Firebase REST Auth documentation, I had to use `signUp` for signup function and `signInWithPassword` for the login function and pass it to the `urlSegment` in the `_authenticate()`.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue while rendering pdf text and html text in API response, I have solve this issue with folowing code. For more refer [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32841).

```
var data= await json.decode(json.encode(response.databody);
```

**Note:** you have to put `json.encode` to relove the issue

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Dio and facing this kind of error then add :

```
responseType: ResponseType.plain,
```

to your dio client. Complete dio client is as follows:

```
final Dio _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
 connectTimeout: 10000,
 receiveTimeout: 10000,
baseUrl: ApiEndPoints.baseURL,
contentType: 'application/json',
 responseType: ResponseType.plain,
 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not getting JSON as response so when you decode, its throwing that exception. Try out the API in postman to see if the response is JSON.

Comment: Is postman different from what I am using? I don't know much about firebase api, so i would appreciate if you could tell me more clearly what I can do to fix my code.